# Python process-subprocess communication

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing

I have two processes. First (main) one is "dealing" with user stuff. Second one is doing some internal stuff and should update its internal state according to user actions. So I've created two pipes. By one I send actions to subprocess, from another I get messages that emits this subprocess.

I wonder about two things:

1. Is this architecture clean enough?
2. Is my usage of python's typing is good?

---

```
import time
from multiprocessing import Pipe
from multiprocessing import Process
from multiprocessing import Queue
from typing import Any
from typing import Dict
from typing import List


class Counter(object):
    _i: int

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self._i = 0

    def drop(self):
        self._i = 0

    def inc(self):
        self._i += 1

    @property
    def i(self) -> int:
        return self._i


class Action(object):
    _data: Dict[str, Any]
    _label: str

    def __init__(self, label: str, data: Dict[str, Any]):
        super().__init__()
        self._data = data
        self._label = label

    @property
    def data(self) -> Dict[str, Any]:
        return self._data

    @property
    def label(self) -> str:
        return self._label


class CounterProcess(Process):
    _counters: Dict[str, Counter]
    _in_queue: Queue
    _out_queue: Queue

    def __init__(self, in_queue: Queue, out_queue: Queue):
        super().__init__()
        self._in_queue = in_queue
        self._out_queue = out_queue
        self._counters = {}
        self._counters["a"] = Counter()
        self._counters["b"] = Counter()

    def run(self):
        for i in range(15):
            time.sleep(0.5)
            self._process_actions()
            self._update()
            self._emit()

    def _dispatch_action(self, action: Action):
        if action.label != "drop":
            return
        if "label" not in action.data:
            return
        self._drop_counter(action.data["label"])

    def _drop_counter(self, label: str):
        if label in self._counters:
            self._counters[label].drop()

    def _emit(self):
        msg = {}
        for c in self._counters:
            msg[c] = self._counters[c].i
        self._out_queue.put(msg)

    def _get_actions(self) -> List[Action]:
        actions = []
        while not self._in_queue.empty():
            actions.append(self._in_queue.get(False))
        return actions

    def _process_actions(self):
        for action in self._get_actions():
            self._dispatch_action(action)

    def _update(self):
        for c in self._counters.values():
            c.inc()


def print_output(queue: Queue, to_receive: int, dt: float):
    while to_receive > 0:
        if not queue.empty():
            print(queue.get(False))
            to_receive -= 1
        time.sleep(dt)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    oq = Queue()
    iq = Queue()

    proc = CounterProcess(iq, oq)
    proc.start()

    print_output(oq, 5, 0.1)

    iq.put(Action(label="drop", data=dict(label="a")))

    # Try to send incorrect actions
    iq.put(Action(label="notdrop", data=dict(lbl="b")))
    iq.put(Action(label="drop", data=dict()))

    print()
    print_output(oq, 5, 0.1)

    iq.put(Action(label="drop", data=dict(label="b")))

    print()
    print_output(oq, 5, 0.1)

    proc.join()
```